# If element has a certain class move all it's classes to another element

Tags: jquery

**I am trying to find if any other classes are found in an element with a certain class and append them to another element.**

My code is below:

```
   <div class="options-container class1 class2 class3-ul class4">
     <ul class="">
      <li>
        <div class="other-element"></div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
    
        $('.options-container').each(function(i){ //holds multiple classes
            
                var classList = $('ul', this).attr('class').split(/\s+/),
                var myClasses = ['class1', 'class2', 'class3']; 
                //what classes to look for and match.    
            
             $.each(classList, function(index, item) {
            
               if (item === myClasses.index()) {
                 $('.other-element').addClass(item); // append matched classes
               }
            
             });
        
        });
```

I'm not sure what I am doing with index...

Basically, I am just trying to find if the div element (.options-container) has certain classes, and if so, move them to the class of the element (.other-element)

Comment: Can you give an example of the HTML you're working with?

Comment: Ok, so your selector is wrong.  You're looking for a sub 'ul' in the 'ul'.  that doesn't exist in your markup. Change `$('ul', this)` to just `$(this)` and see if it starts working

Comment: Check your browser console - you have a syntax error. `Unexpected token var`

Comment: What exactly is `item === myClasses.index()` doing?  I do not see an `index()` method for arrays.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

Comment: @Taplar .index() , not sure if I am using the correct option here..
but in javascript, is would be indexOf

Comment: Basically, I am just try to find if the div element has a list of classes, and if so, move them to the class of other-element @CertainPerformance

Comment: Ok, so that's an error.  It would be `myClasses.indexOf(item) > -1`

Comment: Also, how many `$('.options-container')` elements exist on the page, max?

Comment: @taplar about 3

Comment: Ok, then you have an additional issue with the other element selector being global.  One sec.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
// No need to re-declare this for every iteration
var myClasses = ['class1', 'class2', 'class3'];

$('.options-container').each(function(i) {
  var $this = $(this);
  var classList = $this.attr('class').split(/\s+/);
  var classesToAdd = myClasses.filter(function(element){
    return classList.indexOf(element) > -1;
  });
  
  // Change only the other element that is a child of the ul
  // You can give addClass an array.  You don't have to explicitly
  // loop
  $this.find('.other-element').addClass(classesToAdd);
  
  // From your comments you asked if you could remove the classes
  // from the parent.  You can do that with removeClass.
  $this.removeClass(classesToAdd);
});
```

```css
div.class1.class2.class3 { color: red; }
div.class1.class2 { color: green; }
div.class1 { color: blue; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="options-container class1 class2 class3-ul class3">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <div class="other-element">A</div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="options-container class1 class2 class3-ul">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <div class="other-element">B</div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="options-container class1 class3-ul">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <div class="other-element">C</div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Now do I just do $(this).removeClass(classesToAdd) to remove them from original spot?

Comment: Thank you @Taplar for helping me through it despite others downvoting my question due to some typos.

Comment: @samjco yeah, you can give `removeClass()` an array as well

Comment: For some reason I had to add: `classesToAdd = ''+classesToAdd+'';
classesToAdd = classesToAdd.replace(",", " ");
classesToAdd = classesToAdd.replace(",", " ");` to get the classes to show and remove the commas....Or it just wasn't working - Strange

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.  I've edited the answer above to include the `removeClass()` as well.  As you can see, both the addClass and removeClass work when you inspect the elements.